# CombinedConfiguration.getString(key, defaultValue) is not working in MVN

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have a weird error with my short code. The code is running well when I ran the test class inside IntelliJ and also drone tasks (which just executing command `mvn clean install`).  But error occurred when I tried to run the mvn command using command line.

After debugging, I found out a NullPointerException occurred in the following code:
`combinedConfiguration.getString("application.env", DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT).toLowerCase();`

combinedConfiguration is an instance of `org.apache.commons.configuration2.CombinedConfiguration`.

Based on the API documentation, a method `getString(key, devaultValue)` shall return the defaultValue when key is not exist in CombinedConfiguration. So I totally don't understand why the NullPointerException occurred. Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT is not null?

Comment: @BernardBorg Yes. The `DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT` is not null. As I said, this only occurred when I execute `mvn clean install` locally

Comment: Is the combinedConfiguration null or the combinedConfiguration.getString() result null?

Comment: @BernardBorg combinedConfiguration.getString() is resulting null

Comment: Could you debug the line and tell me what the value of DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT is?

Comment: @BernardBorg the value is `dev` which matched with what I set

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251013/discussion-between-bernard-borg-and-steven-ang).